# How to call OnPlay when using YouTube embedded code in a Blazor WASM project

Tags: blazor

I am using the following to embed a YouTube video in my Blazor WASM project.  I want to know how know when the video is actually played.  There is an IFrame "onplay" method but when I try to tie it to my Blazor method the Blazor method does not get called.

Here is my code:

```
<iframe width="@width" height="@height" src="@url" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen onplay=@OnPlay> </iframe>
```

```
private async Task OnPlay()
{
    // I do something here
}
```

Comment: The iframe is isolated from the host page, but you can tap into player events using the [IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: Thanks Roberto... Unfortunately, I am using Blazor because I know very little javascript...  Perhaps I have no choice but to learn more.